# JavaScript firstChild returns undefined

Tags: javascript, dom

I am just a beginner in DOM manipulation so sorry for a silly question.
I have te following piece of HTML and JS code

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to get the HTML content of the list's first child node.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes.</p>

<p>If you add whitespace before the first LI element, the result will be "undefined".</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var list = document.getElementById("myList").firstChild.innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;
        var x=document.getElementById("myList").childNodes[0];
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=x.nodeName;      
    }
</script>
```

The issue here is that the

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;
```

outputs undefined in the window. However, everything works fine when I use firstElementNode property. Or is it because the first child is Attr corresponding to the ID attribute?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a statement: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = list;`. What do you output that gives `undefined`?

Comment: isn't it supposed to modify the page by printing Coffee?

Comment: hey why down vote. i only forgot typing innerHTML

Answer (score 4):

The solution is very simple. What i did miss that white spaces are also taken into account. So that is why the first

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerhtml
```

gave me undefined. If i remove whitespace and make elements as

```
 <ul id="myList"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
```

everything works.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is solved by the exercise itself:

***Note: Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes. If you add whitespace before the first LI element, the result will be "undefined".***

Since you have a line break after your `ul` element, `firstChild` returns that line break to your `variable` list which is what gives you the undefined.

Answer (score 3):

`firstChild` is the first child node regardless of type. It can be any node type, including text nodes and comments.

`firstElementChild` on the other hand is the first child node that is an element.

In your case, the first child is a text node, specifically the whitespace before the first `<li>` tag.
Text nodes don't have an `innerHTML` property and that's why you get `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

after reading w3schools [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_firstchild.asp) it says that you shuldnt use a whitespace before the li element.
So if you content your ul to look like:

```
<ul id="myList"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
```

the selector shuldnt return undefined